# Redux-Firestore bug #45 | Work Around?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am running into this bug where if I delete a document from firestore my redux store shows it as `null` appose to removing it from the store. If I check firestore, I do indeed see it is deleted.

This causes my front-end to break because my `.map` functions are unable to map null arguments. If could run conditional statements to see if an item in the array is null, then remove this from the array but I wanted to see if there was a more elegant way to handle this bug until it is resolved?

I am using the `firetore.data` store.

### Bug details here

[delete does not remove item from data state # 45](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/issues/45)

[image]

> https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/issues/45

Answer (score 1):

I opted to create my own workaround until this bug is resolved.

Create a if statement to check to see if your state has the data. convert this data to an Array and then filter out any undefined data to create your final array.

```
   // Check to see if data exist
    if (this.props.userData) {
      // Convert data to array
      let data = Object.values(this.props.userData);
      // Filters undefined objects due to react-redux-firestore bug
      data = data.filter(singleData => {
        return singleClass !== undefined;
      });
    }
```